# Trying to save href pulled from website to a document

Tags: python, urllib

So basically I am able to pull all the links I want, but I'm not sure how to then save those links to a txt file. Really I am just trying to pull the full links from the href, not half links or whatever else. This allows me to see the list in console but I'm not sure how to save or even just filter even more. Pretty new to this so if I need to add anything that would help let me know.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def opener():
    opener = request.build_opener()
    opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
    request.install_opener(opener)


def spider(maxPages):
    page = 1
    while page <= maxPages:
        url = "example site" + str(page)
        opener()
        source = request.urlopen(url)
        content = source.read()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(content, features="html.parser")
        for link in soup.findAll("a"):
            src = link.get("href")
            print(src)

        page += 1


spider(1)
```

This code below works but only gives one link in the txt file

```
        for link in soup.findAll("a"):
            src = link.get("href")
            print(src)
            with open('links.txt', 'w') as file:
                file.write(str(src))
```

Comment: Your second code snippet seems to be missing some indentation after the for statement. Is this in line with the code you are running or is it just a mistake when posting the code here? Also, I'd suggest that the with statement goes at an indentation level above the for statement so that the file isn't over written each time you try to add a new link.

Comment: ah yes just a mistake when posting the code here

Answer (score 0):

This is because you always write to a new file in the loop. See on `'w'`. Here is how to fix it.

```
for link in soup.findAll("a"):
    src = link.get("href")
    print(src)
    with open('links.txt', 'a') as file:
        file.write(str(src + '\n'))
```

Use `'a'` to append data in the file.

`\n` will give you a newline each loop

###### Edit: To work with NoneType

```
for link in soup.findAll("a"):
    src = link.get("href")
    if src == None:
        continue
    print(src)
    with open('links.txt', 'a') as file:
        file.write(str(src + '\n'))
```

Comment: this totally makes sense, but now I'm getting this error:

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'

Comment: I believe it's because the next character on the next line is a #, in console it printed out as None

Comment: Why not just open the file once before the for loop?

Comment: this works as well, now just need to find a way around with both NoneType and strings

Comment: just make an `if` statement for it.

`if src == None:`
`continue`

Answer (score 0):

Super simple to fix, just converted the entire list into a string and can easily sort through that. Thanks for the help everyone.

```
        for link in soup.findAll("a"):
            src = str(link.get("href"))
            fw = open('links.txt', 'a')
            fw.write(src + "\n")
            fw.close()
            print(src)
```